# SML function to with 2 lists that returns the XOR---fixed

Tags: list, sml, xor

Anyone able to offer any advice for a function in SML that will take 2 lists and return the XOR of them, so that if you have the lists [a,b,c,d], [c,d,e,f] the function returns [a,b,e,f] ?

I have tried to do it with 2 functions, but even that does not work properly.

```
fun del(nil,L2) = nil
|del(x::xs,L2)=
if (List.find (fn y => y = x) L2) <> (SOME x) then
del(xs, L2) @ [x]
else 
del(xs, L2);

fun xor(L3,L4) = 
rev(del(L3,L4)) @ rev(del(L4,L3));
```

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you mean by the XOR of two lists? Thanks.

Comment: exclusive or, so that if you have the lists [a,b,c,d], [c,d,e,f] the function returns [a,b,e,f]

Comment: So, put another way, you want to remove duplicates between two lists?

Comment: Yes, if the item is in both lists it should not make it into the final list. Only elements unique items should make it into the final list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt seems almost correct, except that `fn x => x = x` does not make sense, since it always returns true. I think you want `fn y => y = x` instead.

A couple of other remarks:

- You can replace your use of `List.find` with `List.filter` which is closer to what you want.
- Don't do `del(xs,L) @ [x]` for the recursive step. Appending to the end of the list has a cost linear to the length of the first list, so if you do it in every step, your function will have quadratic runtime. Do `x :: del(xs,L)` instead, which also allows you to drop the list reversals in the end.
- What you call "XOR" here is usually called the *symmetric difference*, at least for set-like structures.

Comment: Thank you. I was playing around with higher level functions before I knew much about them. Now that I read ahead that makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to filter out duplicates from each list and then concatenate the two resulting lists. Using List.filter you can remove any element that is a member (List.exists) of the other list.

However that is quite inefficient, and the below code is more an example of how not to do it in real life, though it is "functionally" nice to look at :)

```
fun symDiff a b =
    let
      fun diff xs ys =
          List.filter (fn x => not (List.exists ( fn y => x = y) ys)) xs
      val a' = diff a b
      val b' = diff b a
    in
      a' @ b'
    end
```

This should be a better solution, that is still kept simple. It uses the SML/NJ specific ListMergeSort module for sorting the combined list `a @ b`.

```
fun symDiff1 a b =
    let
      val ab' = ListMergeSort.sort op> (a @ b)
      (* Remove elements if they occur more than once. Flag indicates whether x
         should be removed when no further matches are found *)
      fun symDif' (x :: y :: xs) flag  =
          (case (x = y, flag) of
             (* Element is not flagged for removal, so keep it *)
             (false, false) => x :: symDif' (y :: xs) false
             (* Reset the flag and remove x as it was marked for removal *)
           | (false, true) => symDif' (y::xs) false

             (* Remove y and flag x for removal if it wasn't already *)
           | (true, _) => symDif' (x::xs) true)
        | symDif' xs _ = xs
    in
      symDif' ab' false
    end
```

However this is still kind of stupid. As the sorting function goes through all elements in the combined list, and thus it also ought to be the one that is "responsible" for removing duplicates.

Comment: You should come back with a code example. Now there are a lot of SML questions to answer, it feels like a dream :).

Comment: @pad, hehe. As promised, though a bit late. I'll cook up a "better" example in a moment.

Comment: I'd call the auxiliary function `diff` not `filter`. ;)

Comment: Your `symDiff1` is quite a different function, though. Besides sorting the elements in the result (and thus being limited to int lists), it also removes per argument duplicates, which the other does not.

Comment: thank you guys for your effort with helping me with this, just changing the anonymous function for it for me.